# Verify that the prop of a child component is a certain function in Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

when I keep referring to my child component in my tests and I want to check that one of the props going into the child component is a certain function, I keep getting told that the child component is undefined in Jest despite the fact that it is imported and is not undefined when the component renders. The code for the component is as follows:

```
class ActivityItemsDropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { id: '' };
  }
  ...(various methods here)...
  render() {
  const {
    // these props are being dispatched from a redux state
    selectedOption,
    selectNewOption,
    onFilterChange,
    loanDates,
    loans,
    intl,
    } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="dls-accent-gray-03-bg flex flex-align-center">
      <div className="col-md-3 margin-l margin-t pad-0">
        <Dropdown
          id="statements-dropdown"
          options={getOptions(loanDates, loans, intl)}
          value={selectedOption}
          onChange={index => onStatementChange(index,
          loanDates,
          loans,
          selectNewOption,
          onFilterChange)}
          label={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'loanActivityAndHistory.statementDropdown.view' })}
          getOptionLabel={({selectedLabel: label}) => {
          const lines = label.split('-');
          return { firstLine: lines[0], secondLine: lines[1] };
        }}
      />
    </div>
    {selectedOption === CUSTOM
      ? <ActivityItemsDatePicker applyCustomDates={onFilterChange} />
      : ''}
    </div>
    );
   }
  }
```

The uncovered lines that Jest wants tests for are the two lines within the prop getOptionLabel in the Dropdown child component. The Dropdown component is being imported from an API I don't have access to, so I can't see what is going on under the hood with the Dropdown component.

In my Jest file (also using Enzyme) the tests are as follows:

```
const testRecentActivityWhenCurrentStatementPresent = async () => {
  const wrapper = await shallow(<ActivityItemsDropdown
    selectedOption="1"
    selectNewOption={selectNewOption}
    onFilterChange={onFilterChange}
    loanDates={loanDates}
    loans={loans}
    intl={intl}
  />);

  const twoLineLabel = ({selectedLabel: label}) => {
    const lines = label.split('-');
    return { firstLine: lines[0], secondLine: lines[1] };
  }

  const dropdown = wrapper.find('#statements-dropdown');
  expect(dropdown.props().getOptionLabel).to.equal(twoLineLabel);
  dropdown.simulate('change', { value: 'RECENT_ACTIVITY' });
  expect(selectNewOption).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ value: 'RECENT_ACTIVITY' });
  expect(onFilterChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Jun 15, 2018', moment().format('MMM DD, YYYY'));
};
```

The tests have no issue grabbing the dropdown so it can simulate a change, but finds dropdown 'undefined' when I'm trying to find the props it has.

In both my component file and test file I import the Dropdown component from an API I am using (it has no issues accessing the Dropdown component in the ActivityItemsDropdown component file).

The error I receive in Jest is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'equal' of undefined

  175 |
  176 |   const dropdown = wrapper.find('#statements-dropdown');
> 177 |   expect(dropdown.props().getOptionLabel).to.equal(twoLineLabel);
      |   ^
```

I apologize this is really long, but I've been playing around with this for two hours and I'm at my wits end at this point.

Comment: `enzyme.shallow` expects you to only execute tests on the rendered component. However, you could also shallow render the dropdown component using `dropdown.shallow()`. https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which assertion/expect library you're using, but it looks like you took an example from the Enzyme documentation.

Enzyme is using [Chai expect](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) in their examples, while you should be using [Jest expect](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect).

```
expect(dropdown.props().getOptionLabel).toEqual(twoLineLabel);
```

Comment: I still received an error, but it seems like a much more useful error.
    `expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      [Function twoLineLabel]
    Received:
      [Function getOptionLabel]

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

    - [Function twoLineLabel]
    + [Function getOptionLabel] `

Comment: Sorry the format of that code is terrible -_- It won't space well in a comment

Comment: It seems as though Jest does not have a 'deep equal'? I.e. just compare the code within the functions

Comment: `deepEqual` means it will test whether the 2 given objects contain the same properties and values. While `equal` can be compared with `===`. For this reason, 2 separate function definitions will never match. You probably want to test the result of the `getOptionLabel ` function to work as expected.